# Why do I get undefined type using ArrayDeque/Queue java?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayDeque, `ArrayDeque<Double> monthlyFibs` which I initialized by `Queue<Double> monthlyFibs = new ArrayDeque<Double>();`.

However, when I go to call my function, `public ArrayDeque<Double> monthlyPivotBy3Fibonacci(String[][] contents, DecimalFormat df, double fib_constant, ArrayDeque<Double> monthlyFibs)`, in main, like

`dp.monthlyPivotBy3Fibonacci(contents, df, 1.00616, monthlyFibs);` I get an error message that says:

```
    The method monthlyPivotBy3Fibonacci(String[][], DecimalFormat, double,
ArrayDeque<Double>) in the type DataProcess is not applicable for the arguments
 (String[][], DecimalFormat, double, Queue<Double>) DataProcess.java    line 530
    Java Problem
```

I think the problem lies because `monthlyFibs` is declared with `Queue<Double>`, but when I pass `monthlyFibs` in as a `Queue<Double>`, I am unable to use the function `push()`. I get the error message:

```
The method push(double) is undefined for the type Queue<Double>
```

What is the way around this? I am using eclipse (Java) and it suggests that I cast the variable as a `Queue<double>` when I call it in main. Is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the type of `monthlyFibs` as `Deque<Double>` instead of `Queue<Double>`:

```
Deque<Double> monthlyFibs = new ArrayDeque<Double>();
```

and change the method signature to:

```
public Deque<Double> monthlyPivotBy3Fibonacci(String[][], DecimalFormat, double, Deque<Double>)
```

This solves the compilation problem.

The method `push` is defined in the interface `Deque`, but not in `Queue`, hence the compilation problem. 
Please note that `Deque` inherits from `Queue`, and thus `ArrayDeque` implements both interfaces.

Using specific implementation `ArrayDeque` as method parameter type / return value type rarely makes sense, since in ths case you are limiting the method to work with one specific implementation, whereas the method would probably work with any implementation of `Deque`.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Then what is the reason for ever declaring it with `Queue<Double>`? I'm learning Java on the fly and that's how many other websites wrote it.

Comment: @NickPredey, the recommendation is to use interfaces in type declarations, since otherwise you are limiting yourself to one specific implementation only. In your case, this recommendation is still valid, you just used the wrong interface: you should have used `Deque` but you used `Queue`. Maybe you were confused since the interface `Deque` inherits from `Queue`.

Comment: That's what it was. I haven't read enough yet on how to correctly use the different data structures in java.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayDeque inherits Queue so an ArrayDeque is a Queue but the opposite isn't true a Queue isn't an ArrayDeque.

So you just have to declare `monthlyFibs` as `ArrayDeque<Double>`